# Using stack in assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have to write a program which asks the user to enter a floating point number and 
pop the number from the stack into a variable and then push the variable onto the 
stack as a parameter to a function called twice

**I don't understand the part pop the number from the stack into a variable**
As the floating point value has to be read. It must be read into a variable 
Is it possible in assembly to instruct automatically push a value entered by the user into a stack
and then read the value from the stack instead from the console directly?

Comment: Depends on the environment you use. I assume you have some function to read a float, maybe that returns on the FPU stack as would be usual per the 32 bit calling convention. `scanf` on the other hand takes a pointer and reads into memory as you said.

Comment: *It must be read into a variable* - no, it must be read into *memory*, but that can be stack space.  e.g. `lea eax, [esp + 4]` / `push eax`  (or just `push esp` depending on which stack space you want to use) then `push OFFSET format` / `call scanf`.  If by "variable" you mean `label  dd 0.0` (i.e. a C `static` or global variable), then e.g. `pop [label]`.  Otherwise yeah it's weird because stack space already can be considered storage space for *local* variables, like in un-optimized C code.

Comment: MASM calls data labels "variables" so presumably your assignment does mean static storage.  Most other assemblers don't have pretensions of being "high level", and realize that variables are a high-level concept that you can *implement* in assembly using the tools that assemblers give you (labels and static storage, stack space, and registers.)

Comment: I could use floating point instructions here. Like if I use call `ReadFloat` this puts the float entered by user on top of stack `ST(0)` .  Now if I have a variable defined in .data section like `floatValue REAL4 ?` how do I copy the value from ST(0) into floatValue Variable

Comment: Use `FSTP`. Consult an instruction set reference.